# How do I add to a row after already creating the row

Tags: vb.net, datatable

This is a simplifed verson of my code

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable()`
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 0 ") 
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 1") 
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 2 ") 
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 3")
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 4 ") 
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Year 5")
 dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Total")
 dt.Rows.Add("Net Economic Benefit")
```

Which creates a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLR8z.png) (ignore the other rows)

My question is, is there a way for me to add to the row "Net Economic Benefit" ?
The code should basically do what the following code does

```
dt.Rows.Add("Net Economic Benefit", "1", "2", "3")
```

Except I was to create a loop to add the "1", "2", "3" so I cannot use that code as it will create multiple rows.
Code might look something like:

```
dt.Rows.Add("Net Economic Benefit")
dt.Rows("Net Economic Benefit").AddRow("1")
```

Basically it refers to the already added row "Net Economic Benefit" and then it adds the "1", "2", and "3"

Comment: Maybe start with some reading on the DataTable class, specifically the NewRow method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=net-6.0 Which has example usages

Comment: IMO, not clear what you're trying to do. You have 7 Columns in your DataTable, why are you trying to add 4 values? With `Net Economic Benefit` added as the value of the `Year 0` Column. Note that you haven't specified the Type of the Columns (do that before anything else) and you probably don't want to have a `Total` that sums strings. -- Why are you trying to add a Row to a Row? Can you show what the content of this DataTable should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an existing `DataRow`, however you may have created it, you set the fields by indexing the row, either by column name or ordinal:

```vb
Dim row As DataRow

'...

row("SomeColumn") = someValue
row(index) = someOtherValue
```

Comment: I did `Dim row As DataRow = table.Rows(0)`  which reference to the row I want to modify then I did `row("SomeColumn") = someValue` which added the value to `Row(0)` in my table